# Map Reduce Output file is empty

Tags: java, hadoop

I am writing a program in Hadoop to find the highest salaried employee by gender in different age groups, which is running successfully but it's output files are empty. For more info please refer [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/map_reduce/map_reduce_quick_guide.htm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYEvp.png)

Program is

```
public class PartitionerExample extends Configured implements Tool
{
   //Map class

   public static class MapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
   {
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      {
         try{
            String[] str = value.toString().split("\t", -3);
            String gender=str[3];
            context.write(new Text(gender), new Text(value));
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }

   //Reducer class

   public static class ReduceClass extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,IntWritable>
   {
      public int max = -1;
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable <Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
      {
         max = -1;

         for (Text val : values)
         {
            String [] str = val.toString().split("\t", -3);
            if(Integer.parseInt(str[4])>max)
            max=Integer.parseInt(str[4]);
         }

         context.write(new Text(key), new IntWritable(max));
      }
   }

   //Partitioner class

   public static class CaderPartitioner extends
   Partitioner < Text, Text >
   {
      @Override
      public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks)
      {
         String[] str = value.toString().split("\t");
         int age = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);

         if(numReduceTasks == 0)
         {
            return 0;
         }

         if(age<=20)
         {
            return 0;
         }
         else if(age>20 && age<=30)
         {
            return 1 % numReduceTasks;
         }
         else
         {
            return 2 % numReduceTasks;
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public int run(String[] arg) throws Exception
   {
      Configuration conf = getConf();

      Job job = new Job(conf, "topsal");
      job.setJarByClass(PartitionerExample.class);

      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(arg[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(arg[1]));

      job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);

      job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

      //set partitioner statement

      job.setPartitionerClass(CaderPartitioner.class);
      job.setReducerClass(ReduceClass.class);
      job.setNumReduceTasks(3);
      job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

      job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

      System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0 : 1);
      return 0;
   }

   public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception
   {
      int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new PartitionerExample(),ar);
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

The program is running successfully but it's output file is not showing any Output. Here is my output:

[image: screenshot showing output]

Comment: Do you see any exceptions for the map invocation. Based on the counters you have provided it seems that 18 records were read but Map job spit out 0 records. Because Mapper emits 0 records, reducer will not get anything to process and your output file thus will be empty.

Comment: 'WARN io.ReadaheadPool: Failed readahead on ifile
EBADF: Bad file descriptor
' I'am getting this warning

Comment: Perhaps you could see if the partitioner is the problem, you could remove it and use an identity reducer or zero reducers, just to see if the mapper writes out data.

Comment: Could you debug and see if "context.write(new Text(gender), new Text(value));" is executed ?

Comment: can you give the sample data set ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);` should be `job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);`

The reducers signature is `Reducer<Text,Text,Text,IntWritable>`.

Comment: Output is still the same

Answer (score -1):

Your reduce method doesn't override the base class reduce method. Probably adding @Override annotation may solve the problem.

Comment: Adding the annotation will not solve the problem as that annotation is completely optional.

Comment: I'm afraid I thought the '@Override' is used to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its super-classes or parent classes and maybe that was the reason why child class method would get executed. Pardon me if I am wrong but I was dealing with the same issue

Comment: `@Override` signals the compiler that you _intend_ to override a method. It is useful because it causes errors when you use `@Override` and are not in fact overriding anything.